# connect() breaks the socket when the connection is refused

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, solaris

I had been fighting with an error in my program where I got the signal `SIGPIPE` when I tried to `send()` after `connect()`. The error only occurred if `connect()` had gotten "connection refused" at least once. Here's the old buggy code:

```
getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "1443", &hints, &res);
s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
while (connect(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    printf("Error: connection refused");
    sleep(2);
}   

sprintf(msg, "Testing");
msg_len = strlen(msg);
send(s, msg, msg_len, 0);
```

The way I fixed it seems odd to me, and I don't understand why it works. Here is the fixed code:

```
int connect_works = -1;
while(connect_works == -1) {
    getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "1443", &hints, &res);
    s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    connect_works = connect(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

    if (connect_works == -1) {
        printf("Error: connection refused");
        sleep(2);
    }
}

sprintf(msg, "Testing");
msg_len = strlen(msg);
send(s, msg, msg_len, 0);
```

To clarify, either snippet works if the first time `connect()` is called it returns success. However, only the second snippet works if `connect()` has failed one or more times.

Also, this error only occurs when compiled on Solaris. Either works when compiled on Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me understand why you must re-initialize the socket if `connect()` fails?

Comment: Although I have no idea why you need to create a new socket, maybe you should close() the socket when connect() fails... Else you're leaking sockets.

Comment: Where is the outgoing port number assigned? Is that part of socket() or connect()? Is it possible for sockets to exist without having assigned outgoing port numbers?

Comment: The outgoing port number is assigned in connect(), unless you've done an explicitly bind() beforehand, which is usually unnecessary. Why do you ask?

Comment: Just curious, mostly. I had noticed some odd behavior with `netstat` while debugging this issue, but now I think I understand what was going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic principle is that you can't re-connect a TCP socket. Once you've accepted or connected it, even with a failure, you have to close it and create a new one for new connections.